# Using cookieSession with Passport

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, passport.js

I want to use cookie session store with Passport because memory store is not designed for production:

```
Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
```

Here's my Express initialization:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({keepExtensions:true}));
app.use(express.cookieParser(cookieSecret));
app.use(express.cookieSession({ 
    key: cookieKey,
    secret: cookieSecret,
    maxAge: sessionTimeout
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Everything works normally if I change `express.cookieSession` to `express.session`. When using `cookieSession` user login succeeds but the user is not logged in anymore after next page load occurs. Any tips how to make passport work with cookie sessions?

I'm using Express 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

The initialization of `cookieSession` isn't correct. Try this:

```
app.use(express.cookieSession({ 
  key    : cookieKey,
  secret : cookieSecret,
  cookie : {
    maxAge: sessionTimeout
  }
}));
```

Also, make sure that `sessionTimeout` is in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks but didn't help :\

Comment: @MattiLehtinen well it's possible to get it working, I used it myself :) Perhaps you can use your browsers dev tools to see what is being sent back and forth between the browser and the server in terms of cookies and such.

Comment: I'm doing the authentication via ajax POST call and it seems that browser is not setting the cookie although following is returned: `Set-Cookie:local.sess=s%3Aj%3A%7B%22passport%22%3A%7B%22user%22%3A5%7D%7D.OPxdoZ1oPKboHJEhz7uSPJiBxSIRavEByC7f1yEn1Xc; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 17 Oct 2013 16:09:36 GMT; HttpOnly` My server runs on `localhost:3000` and the JS client is loaded from the same server.

Comment: @MattiLehtinen does that expiry time look good to you? Also, are you using a cross-domain AJAX request? If so, have you enabled `withCredentials`?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had the same issue. Turns out you don't need to (in fact you can't) set the `secret` option in both cookieParser and cookieSession.

See my answer on my own post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30109922/3500059