# Cannot get `cookieSession` working with `maxAge`

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

** SOLVED **

I've been struggling with this one for a bit. Lots of similar posts out there, but none of the proposed solutions are working for me.

I'm using Express and Passport with cookie sessions. When I pass just the `secret` to cookieSession everything works fine:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('MySecret'));
app.use(express.cookieSession('MySecret'));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

But the default cookie is session-based, and so it clears when you close your browser. I need a time-limited cookie. So I tried using the supposedly supported options:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('MySecret'));
app.use(express.cookieSession({
  secret: 'MySecret',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

And it stops working. Seemingly the cookie is set in my browser and looks good, but there's no `req.user`, and subsequent requests are not authenticated.

I tried using `maxage` instead of `maxAge` to no avail. I can switch to the same config, but using `express.session()` instead of `express.cookieSession()` and it *does* work, but the session is lost when the server is restarted.

Any help?

edit: I'm on Express 3.20.2 btw

Answer (score 1):

This was user error. I'm not sure where I got the syntax for passing just the `secret` as a string to `cookieSession()` but that's invalid. It gets ignored, and actually falls back to using `req.secret` which is defined by the `cookieParser('MySecret')` call in the first place.

So that's why it was working with the original code. I still think this is a wtf moment though, because the second syntax should still work, but it doesn't. It boils down to this snippet in the `cookieSession` module:

```
if (!options.secret && req.secret) {
  req.session = req.signedCookies[key] || {};
  req.session.cookie = cookie;
} else {
  // TODO: refactor
  var rawCookie = req.cookies[key];
  if (rawCookie) {
    var unsigned = cookieParser.signedCookie(rawCookie, secret);
    if (unsigned) {
      var original = unsigned;
      req.session = cookieParser.JSONCookie(unsigned) || {};
      req.session.cookie = cookie;
    }
  }
}
```

So when you *do* pass a `secret` in the options for `cookieSession` it falls into the `else` block, and ends up setting a different cookie? I don't know, but it seems like a bug. If I'm using the same secret for both `cookieParser` and `cookieSession` it should be good. But anyway...

========

tl;dr it needs to be this:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('MySecret'));
app.use(express.cookieSession({
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  }
}));
```